# Lumia 550 has downloaded photos I do not want and I do not know from where they came from

Tags: photos

I have about 100 family photos appeared on my new Lumia 550 phone. The file information says Source OneDrive (cloud only).I do not know why it has done it or where it has got the photos from. The OneDrive on the PC it is linked to is empty. I do not want the photos on the phone. I do not want to delete them in case it deletes them off the PC or wherever it has got them from as well.If I turn off the link to the OneDrive I lose the connection to OneNote which I want.
I find it scary that the phone has moved all this information without my authority.
How do I find out where the photos come from and stop them being transferred to my phone without deleting them wherever they are.
Thankfully I do not have this problem with my Samsung phone.

Comment: Are you sure you're logging in to OneDrive with the same account from your PC? Have you previously connected any other devices to your OneDrive (such as your Samsung device) - and if so, were any of these devices lost, sold or stolen?

Comment: The PC you checked might not have been set to sync the pictures. Check at https://onedrive.live.com (or with the OneDrive app if using Windows 8.1 or 10). What happens if you turn off "Show my cloud-only content from OneDrive" in the Photos app? Also, are these your photos that you simply do not want to be shown on your phone, or do you believe they're someone else's files?